# On the existence of sets in bijection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Given a set $X\not=\emptyset$ is  it always true that there is a set $Y$ such as $X\not=Y$ but $X$ and $Y$ are in bijection? I think it is true, but which axioms of logic justify it? I mean, if $X=\{a,b,...\}$ is it enough to say: "let $x,y,...$ elements such that $x\not=a, y\not=b$ etc?" What axiom justifies the existence of such $x,y,$ etc?

Probably the question could be extended: why is there always a couple of different isomorphic groups or rings etc..?

Comment: It fails uninterstingly for $X=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither the Axiom of Choice nor the Axiom of Regularity is needed for this.

Given a set $X,$ define $b=\{x\in X:x\notin x\}.$ It is clear that $b\notin X;$ assuming $b\in X$ leads to the contradiction $b\in b\iff b\notin b.$

If $X\ne\emptyset,$ we can choose an element $a\in X;$ then the set
$$Y=(X\setminus\{a\})\cup\{b\}$$
is in bijection with $X,$ and $X\ne Y.$

A similar but slightly more involved argument shows (still without using the Axiom of Choice or the Axiom of Regularity) that, given any set $X,$ we can find a set $Y$ such that $Y$ is in bijection with $X$ and $X\cap Y=\emptyset;$ see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299285/proof-of-exchange-principle-in-set-theory/1240240#1240240).

Now suppose $(G,\cdot)$ is a group. First, we can find a set $H$ which is disjoint from $G$ and in bijection with $G;$ let $f:G\to H$ be a bijection. Then define multiplication on $H$ so that $f$ becomes an isomorphism; namely, for $x,y\in H,$ let $xy=f(f^{-1}(x)f^{-1}(y)).$

Comment: ok thank you, but what about: given a group $G$ there is a different group $G'$ isomorphic to $G$?

Comment: @User12345 A bijection $f:X\to Y$ is given by setting $f(a)=b$ and $f(x)=x$ for $x\ne a.$ No choice needed.

Comment: sorry but if I define an element as an object of a set you didn't prove that $b$ is an element. I know that you're right, so the question is: Is there a more mathematical definition of element? Lastly: $b$ is a set because of the separation axiom right?

Comment: @bof what do you think about it?

Comment: @Richard I'm not sure what your problem is. I defined $b$: $$b=\{x\in X:x\notin x\}.$$ Given a set $X,$ the existence of the subset $\{x\in X:\text{ whatever } \},$ consisting of all elements of $X$ satisfying a given condition, is provided by the [Axiom Schema of Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification), which is part of the ZF axioms.

Comment: At the beginning in the first comment you said: you have to find an ELEMENT $y$ .. but what is an element for you? I mean, in general for me an element is something that belongs to a set but you didn't prove that $b$ belongs to some set. So my question is: Can we define an element to be just a mathematical object without associate it to a set ?

Comment: Would you feel better if I changed the word "element" to "set" or "thing"? In ZF set theory there is only one kind of thing. Everything is a set, and every set is an element of other sets; the pairing axiom says that, for any $x$ and $y$ there is a $z$ such that $x\in z$ and $y\in z$.

Comment: So in ZF theory also every element is defined to be a set? I mean element is synonymous of set? This could clarifies my ideas.

Comment: In ZF set theory "set" is not officially part of the language; "let $x$ be a set" is an informal way of speaking, because officially ***everything*** is a set. (And every set is an element of other sets, by the pairing axiom. I seem to be repeating a previous comment.) (In Morse-Kelley theory, which I consider somewhat exotic, everything is a *class*, and some of them are sets and some are not; and sets are the only things that can be elements.)

Comment: Ok maybe now I got it: In ZF a set is "something" such that every its element is a set and again these sets have other sets as elements etc.. Is it correct?

Comment: As for the $b$ in my answer, it's a subset of $X,$ and a subset of a set is a set even in Morse-Kelley theory. The set $b$ like every set is **AN ELEMENT** of its singleton $\{b\}.$ It's also an element of the power set of $X.$ (Corrected typo in my previous comment.)

Comment: sorry but now I don't think that $\{x\in X:whatever\}$ is a set. The axiom schema of specification does not allow that the property can be whatever. Actually it seems that for the $b$ of your example we have the contradiction: $b\in b$ if and only if $b\not \in b$. (Russel's paradox?)

Comment: Really, "whatever" can be any first-order formula in the language of set theory. In particular, the existence of $\{x\in X:x\notin x\}$ is an instance of the axiom schema of specification. As I noted in my answer, the contradiction "$b\in b\iff b\notin b$" follows from the assumption that $b\in X;$ that's how I proved that $b\notin X.$

Answer (score 1):

The axiom of choice and it's variant forms effectively make this true. The axiom of choice states that for any well-defined collection of indexed nonempty sets X = {$A_i$|$i\in I$} , there exists a mapping f: $X \rightarrow $$\cup X$ such that f($A_i$) = x where x$\in A_i$.  Therefore, it's always possible to define-or "choose"-f in such a way when A,B$\in$ X, f:A$\rightarrow$B is bijective.

One variant of the axiom of choice that give an explicit bijection from X into Y where X,Y $\neq \emptyset$, Tarski's Cartesian product axiom does a great job of this and it's logically equivalent to AOC. Tarski's theorem states that if the Zermelo-Frankel set theory axioms hold, then for every set A, there is a bijective mapping between A and A x A iff AOC is true. The proof-along with the explicit bijection-can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_theorem_about_choice). The proof is rather technical, but it's well worth mastering since to my knowledge,it's the only variant of AOC that explicitly gives the bijection.

Get comfortable using AOC, a LOT of higher mathematics relies either explicitly or implicitly upon it.