# To prove the elementary statement without using AC and AF

Tags: logic, set-theory

I have little knowledge in set theory and I have difficulty in proving the following statement without using **Axiom of Choice** or **Axiom of Foundation**:

Let $A$ be a set. Then there exists a set $B$ satisfying the following conditions:
$A\cap B=0$ and there exists a one-to one function $f$ from $A$ onto $B$.

I considered $A\times \mathscr{P}(A)$, and assumed that $(A\times \{X\})\cap A\neq\varnothing$ for all $X\subset A$. Then, it gives a partition $\mathscr{C}$ of $A$ which seems larger than $A$. However, I failed to complete the proof without using AC, since I needed to construct an one-to-one function from $\mathscr{C}$ into $A$ to complete the proof. I also found the proof using axiom of foundation, but as the statement is elementary, I belive that there might be a way to prove the statement without the above axioms.

In summary, is the statement consistent over $\{ZF-\text{Axiom of Foundation}\}$?

Comment: To define function $a \mapsto a \times \{X\}$ you not need AC or foundation.

Comment: @kp9r4d Of course, the function you mentioned does not need AC of foundation to be defined, but to define a one-to-one function from $\mathscr{D}$ onto $A$ so that I conclude that $\mathscr{P}(A)\leq A$ and get contradiction, I could not avoid using AC.

Comment: Where do you think that you have used choice in your argument?

Comment: @AsafKaragila To construct a one-to-one function from $\mathscr{C}$ into(sorry..I made a typo) $A$, I had to choose a set of representative $\mathscr{R}$ of $\mathscr{C}$ which is a subset of $A$ and has the same cardinality as  $\mathscr{C}$. However, to choose a set of representative of a given partition requires AC. Is there a good way to avoid this?

Comment: Well. unless $A$ is empty, $|A\times\mathcal P(A)|\geq|\mathcal P(A)|>|A|$. So that wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: @AsafKaragila My argument was to show that it contradicts the fact that $A<\mathscr{P}(A)$ if I assume that there is no $X\subset A$ with $A\cap(A\times\{X\})=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copying my (unaccepted) answer to [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299285/proof-of-exchange-principle-in-set-theory):

**Lemma.** Given a set $A$, we can find a set $B$ such that $|A|=|B|$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset.$

**Proof.** Let
$$T=\{(S,a):S\subseteq A,\ a\in A,\ (S,a)\in A,\ (S,a)\notin S\}\subseteq A$$
and let
$$B=\{(T,a):a\in A\}.$$
Clearly $|A|=|B|.$ Assume for a contradiction that $A\cap B\ne\emptyset,$ i.e., there is an element $a\in A$ such that $(T,a)\in A.$ Then we get the Russell paradox in the form
$$(T,a)\in T\iff(T,a)\notin T.$$

Comment: So the strategy is to cleverly derive the form of Russell paradox. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This somewhat depends on how you are coding ordered pairs, as there are many ways to do so. But ultimately this consists of two steps:

1. Find some $x$ such that $x$ is not in any ordered pair which may appear in $A$; and
2. define $B$ to be $A\times\{x\}$.

Neither step is particularly difficult. Consider $X=\{u\mid\exists a(\langle a,u\rangle\in A\}\}$. Next define $x=\{S\in X\mid S\notin S\}$. The standard Russell argument shows that $x\notin X$, otherwise $x\in x$ and $x\notin x$.

Next, note that $f(a)=\langle a,x\rangle$ is a defined function, and indeed a bijection between $A$ and $A\times\{x\}$. Finally, if $u\in A\cap (A\times\{x\})$, then $u$ is an ordered pair of the form $\langle a,x\rangle$, in which case $x\in X$ by the definition of $X$; and since $x$ was taken as an element which is not in $X$, this is impossible.