# Explicit set-theoretic construction of a disjoint set with same cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there a set-theoretic construction, given an arbitrary set $S$, of a set $S'$ that is equicardinal with $S$ but is disjoint from $S$?

Comment: Under which set theory?

Comment: @KennyLau ZFC set theory.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2429169/to-prove-the-elementary-statement-without-using-ac-and-af) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299285/proof-of-exchange-principle-in-set-theory).

Comment: Is S a subset of S'?  If so, then for S' to be disjoint and equinumerous to S, both have to be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt. Consider O to be an ordinal whose cardinality is larger ,than that of any element of S. Then take S' to be the set of disjoint unions of elements of S with O. There is an obvious bijection between S and S' and these two sets must be disjoint due to their elements having distinct cardinals.