# Finding Equinumerous Set without Using Axiom of Regularity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given two sets $A,B$ show that there exists a set $C$ such that |$C| = |A|$ and $C$ is disjoint
from $B.$

Is it possible to prove this without using the axiom of regularity? By assuming the axiom of regularity, we can use $\{B\}\times A$ and this will be the desired $C$. However, since this question appears before the chapter about the axiom of regularity, I wonder if the author assumes there is a way to prove it without using assuming that axiom.

Comment: Who is the author? What book is this from?

Comment: "since this question appears before the chapter..." Where? As written, this sentence makes no sense to anybody else.

Comment: I probably should not add this sentence .... Basically I just want to try to solve it without using Axiom of Regularity.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I'm confused. You deleted the "set theory" tag and left the "elementary set theory" tag. And yet, on [this seemingly almost identical question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299285/proof-of-exchange-principle-in-set-theory), Asaf Karagila deleted the "elementary set theory" tag and left "set theory". What's the big difference between the two questions? Or am I just confused and misreading the edit histories or something?

Comment: @bof Probably on different days Asaf and I do not coincide on exactly everything. It is weird... Feel free to edit the tags (here or there) to what you think is appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(I'm copying the answer I gave to [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299285/proof-of-exchange-principle-in-set-theory). I don't think this question is a duplicate, because that other question actually asked "How would one use the Axiom of Foundation . . .", which request I ignored by giving a construction without using that axiom.)

**Lemma.** Given a set $X$, we can find a set $Y$ such that $|X|=|Y|$ and $X\cap Y=\emptyset.$

**Proof.** Let
$$T=\{(S,x):S\subseteq X,\ x\in X,\ (S,x)\in X,\ (S,x)\notin S\}\subseteq X$$
and let
$$Y=\{T\}\times X=\{(T,x):x\in X\}.$$
Clearly $|X|=|Y|.$ Assume for a contradiction that $X\cap Y\ne\emptyset,$ i.e., there is an element $x\in X$ such that $(T,x)\in X.$ Then we get the [Russell paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox) in the form
$$(T,x)\in T\iff(T,x)\notin T.$$

**Theorem.** Given sets $A$ and $B,$ we can find a set $C$ such that $|C|=|A|$ and $C\cap B=\emptyset.$

**Proof.** Let $X=A\cup B.$ By the lemma, we can find a set $Y$ such that $X\cap Y=\emptyset$ and $|Y|=|X|=|A\cup B|\ge|A|.$ Choose $C\subseteq Y$ with $|C|=|A|.$

Comment: Very neat proof! Thank you for your help, BOF.

Comment: That was my bad. I accepted your answer.