# Given $S \hookrightarrow T$ construct $U ≈ T$ disjoint from $S$ in Z set theory?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, well-orders

I was recently thinking about the fact (in ZFC) that, given a (first-order) structure $A$ that embeds into another structure $B$, there is some structure $C$ isomorphic to $B$ such that the domain of $A$ is a subset of the domain of $C$. This is trivial if we can prove the following:

> Given any injection from $S$ into $T$, there is some set $U$ disjoint from $S$ that bijects with $T$.

I can prove this within either ZC (using AC) or ZF (using Foundation). My ZC proof uses transfinite induction to pick $U$ out from $(P(T)×2)∖S$. My ZF proof constructs $U = \{ \{S,x\} : x∈T \}$. But I don't see a way to prove it within just Z. In one attempt, I tried to use one of $k$ disjoint copies of $T$ where $k$ is a well-ordered set that does not inject into $S$, but if every copy intersects $S$ then I seem to need a choice function on $S$ to obtain a contradiction. At least this means that I can prove it for countable $S$, but what about uncountable $S$?

I may be missing something easy, because intuitively it cannot be possible that every set that bijects with $T$ has a non-empty intersection with $S$, even in the absence of choice...

Comment: I feel this might have been asked before. But I'm not sure to what extent that would answer the question. If someone finds a duplicate, I'd be happy to delete my answer and close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: To your question, by the way, in the title, recall that choice is needed to prove that power sets of infinite sets are Dedekind-infinite. In particular, if $S$ is a set with a Dedekind-finite power set, then $\mathcal P(S)\setminus S$ is strictly smaller.

Comment: (@Asaf or $S\cap\mathcal P(S)=\emptyset$ :-) )

Comment: @Andrés: I meant, of course, the obvious copy of $S$ into its singletons... :-)

Comment: @Asaf Of course...

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Oh whoops I didn't change the title, which was one of the ways I was trying (and not succeeding). But in fact I was really thinking of how to find a bijection between $P(S)$ and $P(S)∖S$ without copying $S$ into singletons. Anyway I'd better fix the title. =)

Comment: What is the injection for? What changes if you replace "Given $S\hookrightarrow T$ construct" with "Given $S$ and $T$ construct"?

Comment: I don't know if [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2961610/finding-equinumerous-set-without-using-axiom-of-regularity) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299285/proof-of-exchange-principle-in-set-theory) is a duplicate or not, because I'm not sure what is allowed in Z set theory. Anyway the proofs in the answers to those questions seem much longer and more complicated than Asaf's answer.

Comment: @bof: Well Z (Zermelo's original version without choice) is the same as ZFC except you can't use AC or Replacement or Foundation. And Asaf's answer here uses essentially the same trick as your answer there, and probably that's why he felt this has been asked before. =)

Comment: As for the injection, it's because my motivation was that $A$ embeds into $B$, so of course the domain of $A$ injects into the domain of $B$. But as your answers show, we don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a more satisfying answer that does not involve asking whether a set is a member of itself, so it works even in other set theories where members of $S,T$ might be urelements.
$
\def\pow{\mathcal{P}}
$

Let $f$ be a function on $\pow(S)$ where $f(Y) = \{Y\}×T$ for each $Y∈\pow(S)$. Note that $f(Y)$ bijects with $T$ for every $Y∈\pow(S)$. We shall show that $f(Y) ∩ S = ∅$ for some $Y∈\pow(S)$.

Let $g$ be a function on $S$ such that:

- $g(x) = Y$ if $x ∈ f(Y)$ for some (unique) $Y∈\pow(S)$. (Uniqueness is guaranteed because $f(Y) ∩ f(Z) = ∅$ for every $Y,Z∈\pow(S)$ such that $Y ≠ Z$.)
- $g(x) = S$ if $x ∉ f(Y)$ for every $Y∈\pow(S)$.

If $f(Y) ∩ S ≠ ∅$ for every $Y∈\pow(S)$, then for every $Y∈\pow(S)$ there is some $x∈S$ such that $x ∈ f(Y)$, which implies that $g$ is a surjection onto $\pow(S)$, contradicting Cantor's theorem.

Comment: I'm confused about your comment regarding urelements. Since urelements don't have elements, in what sense do they have cardinality other than $0$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: If $a$ is a urelement, then it does not 'make sense' to query whether $a∈a$ or not. I know we can 'evade' this issue by just stipulating "$a∉a$", but I was not satisfied with solutions that require this membership query in the first place, as it does not translate well to systems with strict typing. The solution I finally found does not have this issue. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: Not really. Urelements are not sets, period. That's their schtick, so I don't know how they can have cardinality or be disjoint from something else, as both of these are properties of sets.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I think you misread something; I didn't ever talk about cardinality or disjointness of an urelement. In my post we only deal with functions (including bijections or surjections) on sets. And that's what makes it different from your post, in which you do query membership in $a$, but $a$ is not guaranteed to be a set in a set theory with urelements.

Comment: Okay, I suppose. Even if you have urelements, either they don't have members or you can restrict to the elements of your set which are sets and do no contain themselves.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yes, that works for some set theories with urelements (e.g. ZFA). Nevertheless, for some systems I am playing with, that's not possible because we cannot query whether an arbitrary object is a set or not. A bit hard to explain why, but as you can see the solution I found avoids querying about that as well.

Answer (score 3):

Well. Recall that in presence of Separation every set $A$ has a subset which is not an element of $A$. This is given by $\{a\in A\mid a\notin a\}$.

We can utilize a similar trick to get this disjoint copy. Fix your favorite method to code ordered pairs in $\sf Z$. Now consider $S'=\{x\in\operatorname{dom} S\mid x\notin x\}$, where $\operatorname{dom} S$ is the set of all left-coordinates of ordered pairs which are members of $S$.

By the usual argument, $S'$ is not in the domain of $S$. Now take $U=\{S'\}\times T$.